# In my Table View I have no cell only section so, how can I Reload tableview in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried the reload method in TableView

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

and also tried

```
for (int i = 0; i<self->allMessageKey.count; i++) {                    

    NSIndexSet *sec = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:i];
    [self->chatTableView beginUpdates];

    //NSIndexPath *section = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:i];

    [self->chatTableView insertSections:sec withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

    if (i == self->allMessageKey.count-1)
    {
        [self->chatTableView endUpdates];

        NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSNotFound inSection:self->allMessageKey.count-1];

        [self->chatTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
    }

}
```

the data didn't reload in tableview. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you clarify how would you have a section without a cell?

Comment: where you can reload tableview ?

Comment: you should add some more details about your code. We can just see how you try to reload but not how you set up the variables and delegates of the TableView

Answer (score 0):

only section no cell?

I've had similar problems

some request is not finished,you reload it
you need wait it finished,

Comment: If this was the answer, it would be nice to add make understand what exactly was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`[self.tableView reloadData]` will definitely trigger a reloading of the table view.

I would recommend to check that your `self.tableView` property is definitely pointing at the `UITableView` instance (I assume it's an `IBOutlet` to be joined up in Interface Builder).

You can verify that it is reloading by adding either a breakpoint or a print statement to your `numberOfSections` and/or `numberOfRowsInSection` methods in the delegate. It's possible that it is reloading, but doesn't look like it due to a problem with your model.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I reload the table view. I create a method **reloadTable**

```
-(void)reloadTable{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

and call this method wherever I need it using this code-

```
[self  reloadTable];
```

for better understanding I'm reloading my table after a button click where I'm changing the constraint constants of table view. This is an example for you to understand it properly-

```
-(IBAction)addChemical1:(id)sender{

    _ans6Constraint.constant=1500;

    [self  reloadTable];
}
```

I hope it helps.